# Error: Could not find or load main class GraphCreator.java

Tags: java, class

I have the following 3 Java classes which are supposed to emulate the Google page ranking algorithm:

Node.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Node {
    private String nodeDesc;
    private List<String> inLinks;
    private List<String> outLinks;
    private float oldPageRank;
    private float newPageRank;

    public Node(String nodeDesc) {
        super();
        this.nodeDesc = nodeDesc;
        inLinks = new ArrayList<String>();
        outLinks = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    public String getNodeDesc() {
        return nodeDesc;
    }
    public void setNodeDesc(String nodeDesc) {
        this.nodeDesc = nodeDesc;
    }
    public List<String> getInLinks() {
        return inLinks;
    }
    public void setInLinks(List<String> inLinks) {
        this.inLinks = inLinks;
    }
    public List<String> getOutLinks() {
        return outLinks;
    }
    public void setOutLinks(List<String> outLinks) {
        this.outLinks = outLinks;
    }
    public void setOutLink(String destDesc)
    {
        this.outLinks.add(destDesc);
    }
    public void setInLink(String srcDesc)
    {
        this.inLinks.add(srcDesc);
    }
    /**
     * @return the oldPageRank
     */
    public float getOldPageRank() {
        return oldPageRank;
    }
    /**
     * @param oldPageRank the oldPageRank to set
     */
    public void setOldPageRank(float oldPageRank) {
        this.oldPageRank = oldPageRank;
    }
    /**
     * @return the newPageRank
     */
    public float getNewPageRank() {
        return newPageRank;
    }
    /**
     * @param newPageRank the newPageRank to set
     */
    public void setNewPageRank(float newPageRank) {
        this.newPageRank = newPageRank;
    }
}
```

Graph.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Graph {
    private Map<String, Node> nodes;
    private static int length ;

    private Graph() {
        nodes = new HashMap<String, Node>();
    }

    public static Graph createGraph(File file,int forStartingPageRank) {
        Graph graph = new Graph();


        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String firstLine = reader.readLine();
            float length=Float.parseFloat(firstLine.split(" ")[0]);
            setLength((int)(length));
            Float initialPageRank = null;
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.000000");

            switch (forStartingPageRank) {
            case 0:
                initialPageRank=Float.parseFloat(df.format(0));
                break;
            case 1:
                initialPageRank=Float.parseFloat(df.format(1));
                break;
            case -1:
                initialPageRank=Float.parseFloat(df.format(1/length));
                break;
            case -2:
                initialPageRank=Float.parseFloat(df.format(1/Math.sqrt(length)));
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            String edge;
            int i = 0;
            while ((edge = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] nodePair = edge.split(" ");
                    String srcDesc = nodePair[0];
                    String destDesc = nodePair[1];
                    Node srcNode = graph.getNode(srcDesc);
                    if (srcNode == null) {
                        srcNode = new Node(srcDesc);
                        srcNode.setOutLink(destDesc);
                        srcNode.setOldPageRank(initialPageRank);
                        graph.nodes.put(srcDesc, srcNode);
                    } else {
                        srcNode.setOutLink(destDesc);
                    }
                    Node destNode = graph.getNode(destDesc);
                    if (destNode == null) {
                        destNode = new Node(destDesc);
                        destNode.setInLink(srcDesc);
                        destNode.setOldPageRank(initialPageRank);
                        graph.nodes.put(destDesc, destNode);
                    } else {
                        destNode.setInLink(srcDesc);
                    }
                }
            reader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return graph;
    }

    public Map<String, Node> getNodes() {
        return nodes;
    }

    public Node getNode(String nodeDesc) {
        return nodes.get(nodeDesc);
    }
    public void display(int forItration)
    {
        TreeMap<String, Node> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, Node>(nodes);
        Iterator<String> i = treeMap.keySet().iterator();
        int j =1;
        float sum = 0f;
        DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat("#.000000");
        //df.setMaximumFractionDigits(6);
        int p;
        if(forItration== 0){
            p=999;
        }else{
            p=forItration;
        }
        float temp = nodes.get(i.next()).getOldPageRank();
        System.out.print("Base\t : 0"+" :");
        for(Map.Entry<String,Node> entry : treeMap.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Node node = nodes.get(key);
            System.out.print("P["+node.getNodeDesc()+"] = "+df1.format(temp) +" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        while(j<=p){
            if(j<=9){
                System.out.print("Iter\t : 0"+j+" :");
            }else{
                System.out.print("Iter\t : "+j+" :");
            }
            for(Map.Entry<String,Node> entry : treeMap.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                sum =0f;
                Node node = nodes.get(key);
                    //System.out.println("Inlinks : "+node.getInLinks());
                List<String> inLinkNodes = node.getInLinks();
                for (String inLinkNode : inLinkNodes) {
                    Node tempNode = nodes.get(inLinkNode);
                    sum=sum+(tempNode.getOldPageRank()/tempNode.getOutLinks().size());
                }
                float newPageRank = 0.0375f+0.85f*(sum);
                node.setNewPageRank(Float.parseFloat(df1.format(newPageRank)));
                System.out.print("P["+node.getNodeDesc()+"] = "+df1.format(newPageRank) +" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            j++;
            int m=0;
            for(Map.Entry<String,Node> entry : treeMap.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                sum =0f;
                Node node = nodes.get(key);
                if(node.getOldPageRank()-node.getNewPageRank()<0.0001){
                    m++;
                }
                node.setOldPageRank(node.getNewPageRank());
            }
            if(m==getLength() && forItration == 0){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * @return the length
     */
    public static int getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    /**
     * @param length the length to set ---git 
     */
    public static void setLength(int length) {
        Graph.length = length;
    }
}
```

GraphCreator.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class GraphCreator {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int forItration =-9;
        int forStartingPageRank=-9;
        String fileName = null;

        if(args.length!=3){
            System.out.println("Please pass Three argument ...");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        try{
            forItration = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            forStartingPageRank = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            fileName = args[2];
        }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            System.out.println("Invalid Arguments ...");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Creating Graph..");

        Graph graph = Graph.createGraph(new File(fileName),forStartingPageRank);//"nodes.txt"
        System.out.println("Graph created.");
        graph.display(forItration);
        //System.out.println(graph.getNodes());
    }
}
```

I have compiled all 3, however I've gone through numerous websites that address this issue and none seem to work. Is there an issue with how GraphCreator.java references the other classes?

[image: Dir]

Comment: How do you compile these classes and how do you run them? What does your compile destination dir look like?

Comment: I compiled them using the simple javac command (bash shell), and I run them using `java GraphCreator.java`

Comment: You run using the class name, not the source file name. Try: `java GraphCreator`

Comment: Have you declared the classes as being in a package?

Comment: @AJNeufeld The source code in the post doesn't have a package declaration.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele And many times the source code does show any import statements.  Doesn’t mean there aren’t any.  I agree the problem is likely the `.java` in the run command.  Saw that, and upvoted it after my comment was posted.